# Partial view not rendering and Action method being called twice

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to populate and render a webgrid via a partial view and ajax when a button is clicked. I have two issues. 1. The partial grid doesn't ever seem to populate and render on screen, though I have a breakpoint in the partial view and I see it getting hit. 2. The Action method gets called twice, but the second time it errors out. I wonder if this is causing one.

Main View:

```js
  $(function () {
        $("#btnGetOpsLog").click(function () {

            var numberOfRecords = $("#ddlNumberOfRecords").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("NumberOfRecordsChanged")',
                data: { numberOfRecords: numberOfRecords }
            }).success(function (result) {
                $('#Grid').html(result);
            }).error(function (xhr, status) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            });
        });
    });
```

```html
<div class="row">
    @Html.DropDownList("ddlNumberOfRecords", Model.NumberOfRecordsSelectList, "Select", new { id = "ddlNumberOfRecords" })
    <input type="button" id="btnGetOpsLog" value="Get Logs" />
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div id="Grid">
    @Html.Partial("_OperationLogs")
</div>
```

This is my partial view

```html
@model Assurant.Integration.ServiceRegistry.ServiceRegistryWebUI.Models.OperationLogViewModel
    
@{
    if (Model != null && Model.Logs != null && Model.Logs.Any())
    {
        var grid = new WebGrid(null, defaultSort: "Name", rowsPerPage: Model.NumberOfRecords);
        grid.Bind(Model.Logs, rowCount: Model.Logs.Count, autoSortAndPage: false);
        grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);
        
        grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "display",
            alternatingRowStyle: "alt");
    }
}
```

And finally, my action method:

```
public ActionResult NumberOfRecordsChanged(int? numberOfRecords)
    {
        if (numberOfRecords.HasValue)
        {
            var model = new OperationLogViewModel
            {
                Logs =
                    _serviceManager.GetOperationLogs(numberOfRecords.Value, 0,
                        new Guid("45726746-f62d-41cb-bdba-bc4c6ab6cc43"),
                        new Guid("ef8c3e19-179e-4303-afbb-21613c148b50")).ToList(),
                NumberOfRecordsSelectList = new SelectList(new List<int> { 25, 50, 75, 100 }),
                NumberOfRecords = numberOfRecords.Value
            };

            return PartialView("_OperationLogs", model);
        }

        return Json(new { ok = false, message = "Broken" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I seem to be doing what I have seen others do, but clearly something is amiss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The first time the page loads you are not passing the model:

   `@Html.Partial("_OperationLogs")`

So this is ignored by the statement `if (Model != null ..` in the partial.

Change it to:

```
@Html.Partial("_OperationLogs", Model)
```

2. It gets called twice because you are not preventing the button default and your form is being submitted again, without the `numberOfRecords` having a value.

Fix that with `preventDefault`:

```
 $("#btnGetOpsLog").click(function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
```

**Update**

As per comments, the `grid.GetHtml` is evaluated within an expression without the `@` in front.

Comment: That didn't change anything. It still calls my action method twice when I click the button and doesn't ever render the grid despite hitting the code on the partial view.

Comment: preventDefault didn't stop it. I am stilling seeing that JSON error when I go to http://localhost:52822/Home/NumberOfRecordsChanged from the network tab in chrome.

Comment: @g.t.w.d You button type should be `type="submit"`. To render your grid you need `@grid.GetHtml` too.

Comment: I have @grid.GetHtml in my partial view as shown in my original post.

Submit type still calls it twice.

Comment: @g.t.w.d You have `grid.GetHtml` within an expression without the `@` in front.

Comment: Wow. That was it. Thanks. What does the @ do for it?

Comment: g-t-w-d no probs, it makes it render the markup out as the webgrid is an HTML helper. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your PartialView result to a string and pass that back from your `NumberOfRecordsChanged`.  here is a code snippet on how to convert a partial view to a string

```
protected string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
            viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

        ViewData.Model = model;

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter()) {
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
            ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

Then your ActionResult would look like

```
public ActionResult NumberOfRecordsChanged(int? numberOfRecords)
    {
        if (numberOfRecords.HasValue)
        {
            var model = new OperationLogViewModel
            {
                Logs =
                    _serviceManager.GetOperationLogs(numberOfRecords.Value, 0,
                        new Guid("45726746-f62d-41cb-bdba-bc4c6ab6cc43"),
                        new Guid("ef8c3e19-179e-4303-afbb-21613c148b50")).ToList(),
                NumberOfRecordsSelectList = new SelectList(new List<int> { 25, 50, 75, 100 }),
                NumberOfRecords = numberOfRecords.Value
            };

            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return Json(new { ok = true, message = "", operationLogs = RenderPartialViewToString("_OperationLogs", model) }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            { 
                return PartialView("_OperationLogs", model); 
            }
            return Content(RenderPartialViewToString("_OperationLogs", model));
        }

        return Json(new { ok = false, message = "Broken" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Your script

```
$(function () {
        $("#btnGetOpsLog").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var numberOfRecords = $("#ddlNumberOfRecords").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("NumberOfRecordsChanged")',
                data: { numberOfRecords: numberOfRecords }
            }).success(function (result) {
                $('#Grid').html(result.operationLogs);
            }).error(function (xhr, status) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            });
        });
    });
```

You already figured out what your partial view should look like